# JavaFX: FXML how to make Buttons take the whole width of parent container

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have the following code:

```xml
<VBox id="menu" styleClass="menu" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.app.menu.MenuController">

    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@menu.css"/>
    </stylesheets>

        <Button text="Customers" onAction="#handleCustomers" />
        <Button text="Suppliers" onAction="#handleSuppliers" />
        <Separator/>
        <Button text="Families" onAction="#handleFamilies" />
        <Button text="Products" onAction="#handleProducts" />
        <Separator/>
</VBox>
```

This generates a stacked set of buttons (as desired) but they do not take over the whole width of the container.

[image: JavaFXButtons1]

If I try this:

I have the following code:

```xml
<VBox id="menu" styleClass="menu" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.app.menu.MenuController">

    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@menu.css"/>
    </stylesheets>


    <AnchorPane>
        <Button text="Customers" onAction="#handleCustomers" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"/>
        <Button text="Suppliers" onAction="#handleSuppliers" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"/>
        <Separator/>
        <Button text="Families" onAction="#handleFamilies" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"/>
        <Button text="Products" onAction="#handleProducts" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"/>
        <Separator/>
    </AnchorPane>

</VBox>
```

Then I get the buttons resized horizontally, but they are no longer stacked. I am not being able to implement this in Java FX using FXML.

[image: JavaFX FXML 2]

The desired output would be this:

[image: JavaFX FXML 3]

Comment: What is the expectation ? Can you provide an expected image ?

Comment: Edited to include expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a sufficiently large value for the `maxWidth` property of the buttons:

```xml
<VBox id="menu" styleClass="menu" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.app.menu.MenuController">

    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@menu.css"/>
    </stylesheets>

        <Button text="Customers" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onAction="#handleCustomers" />
        <Button text="Suppliers" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onAction="#handleSuppliers" />
        <Separator/>
        <Button text="Families" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onAction="#handleFamilies" />
        <Button text="Products" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onAction="#handleProducts" />
        <Separator/>
</VBox>
```

This allows the `Button`s to grow beyond the size calculated based on the text.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not know about your stylesheet, you can achieve using your custom stylesheet. Besides, you can manually set the prefered width and height. I provide below the fxml code snippet.

```
<AnchorPane focusTraversable="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.161" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="5.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="593.0" text="Customer" />
      <Button layoutX="4.0" layoutY="51.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="593.0" text="Supplier" />
      <Button layoutX="4.0" layoutY="89.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="593.0" text="Families" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

You can see the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you have several buttons, if I were to assume that you want them all to be the same size then I would do something like:

```
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button1" />
      <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button2" />
      <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button3" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

This would make it so that the buttons would always fill up the width of its parent, meaning that the buttons will dynamically scale with the VBox. All I did was that I set the Max width to MAX_VALUE and made sure that the Pref width was set to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE.

The FXML I provided above results in:

[image]

Comment: oops, I missed that Fabian gave a similar answer. +1 on his answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be comething like that

```
<AnchorPane>
    <Node fx:id="node" prefWidth="${node.parent.width}"></Node>
</AnchorPane>
```